# Shortcut for toggling the space bar's function

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, script, autohotkey, code

I'm trying to make an AutoHotkey script for making Ctrl+Space toggle the space bar's function. The default function is space. When Ctrl+Space is pressed, the function changes to em space. Search em space if you don't know it. When Ctrl+Space is pressed anew, it goes back to space. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I have two scripts right now. One has a code that changes the space bar's function to em space. The other doesn't have that code.

Comment: So, you are having problem with the toggling part ?

Comment: Can you provide the script you are using ?

Comment: `*Space::
`{
`SendInput { }
`}
return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this script, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will "Toggle" the space key's Mode.

```
IsEmSpaceOff := true

^Space:: 
if(IsEmSpaceOff)
IsEmSpaceOff := false
else
IsEmSpaceOff := true
return

#if !IsEmSpaceOff
Space::SendInput { }
```

Comment: It works, but when I restart my PC, the default is em space. I tried understanding your code, but to no end. How can you make space the default?

Comment: You mean that after restarting the PC and running the script again you get "EM space" as default ? But I'm not having this issue at mine.
Is it the case that you want `em space` to be the 'Default action' of Space Bar ? I can't understand your issue.

Comment: After restarting my PC, I get em space by default. I want space to be the default, not em space.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other script interfering ? Because I also tried it and I am not having the same problem. Script has default set to Normal Space, so that should not be a problem. Check for any other  auto-running.

Comment: I fixed it. There's nothing wrong with your code. Thanks for the code.

Comment: @Lamb: Why not simplify all that `if(IsEmSpaceOff) IsEmSpaceOff := false else IsEmSpaceOff := true` by replacing it with a simple `IsEmSpaceOff := !IsEmSpaceOff`?